# Interval Censored data for WeibullFitter in Lifelines python module

Tags: python, weibull-distribution, interval-censoring, lifelines

I am getting different answer using lifelines module for interval censored data fitting using `WeibullFitter()` function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['left'] = [0.1,30.1,60.1,90.1,120.1,150.1,180.1,210.1]
df['right'] = [30,60,90,120,150,180,210,np.inf]
df['Observed'] = 0 # Means exact fail time is not known
df['#Units'] = [14,13,8,5,6,6,25,15930]

from lifelines import WeibullFitter

wf = WeibullFitter()
wf.fit_interval_censoring(df['left'],df['right'],event_observed=df['Observed'],weights=df['#Units'])

wf.print_summary()
```

Actual answer from Reliasoft is lambda_ = 51248, rho_ = 0.97 whereas above code using lifelines v0.24.5 is giving me lambda_ = 6447 and rho_=0.21

The last row in data is a right censored data.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

author here. Looks like there was a bug in a recent version of lifelines for interval censoring. I'll publish a fix today (to release v0.24.5). If you need, rolling back to 0.24.3 will fix it.

I'll have to review how this bug got through testing.

Comment: https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines/pull/1004/files#r418674785 here's the diff

Comment: Thank you for releasing v0.24.5....It works for above example now.

Comment: I got another example where it deviates from answer without giving any warning messages. I will update the new problem in the original problem. Appreciate the help in advance! Awesome job with lifelines by the way!

Comment: hm, I get the same solution as Reliasoft locally. See https://imgur.com/a/wDYk50L - can you confirm your scipy and numpy versions?

Comment: Apologize.....error is from my side. I forgot to include ".1" in df['left'] and it makes quite a difference. It is working as intended now. Thanks a lot for the help and overall lifelines. This package serves my purpose perfectly!!!

Comment: x_left = [0.1,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240]
x_right = [30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,np.inf]
number = [2,5,1,9,6,6,5,2,2645]
censor = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]